# Compare string with arraylist element and get another arraylist element

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<String> endDuration(String searchedKey, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> keys, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size() && i < values.size(); i++) {
        if (searchedKey.equals(keys.get(i))) {
            return values.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am having two lists both are string lists. Also I am having one string.

I want to compare the string with first list of all strings if any of the list values matches with string. I want to get string value from second list in that position.

**Eample:**

```
ArrayList<String> strvalue = (a,b,c,d,e)
ArrayList<String> intValues = (1,2,3,4.5)
String str=c;
```

I want to get integer value 3.

Comment: better idea: use a proper data structure. don't use [parallel arrays](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pretty Simple stuff. You can use the following code:

```
public int getSecondListValue(ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2, String compare) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size() && i < list2.size(); i++) {
        if (list1.get(i).equals(compare)) 
            return list2.get(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks its working.its my mistake only instead of passing array i had used arrayOfarray List that's why it doesn't work .now its working  and again thank you for your suggestion

Comment: happy to help you.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple stuff. You can use the following code:

```
public static List<String> endDuration(String searchedKey, List<List<String>> keys, List<List<String>> values) {
    Iterator<List<String>> itKey = keys.iterator();
    Iterator<List<String>> itValue = values.iterator();
    Set<String> uniqueKeys = new HashSet<>();

    while (itKey.hasNext() && itValue.hasNext()) {
        List<String> v = itValue.next();
        uniqueKeys.clear();
        uniqueKeys.addAll(itKey.next());

        if (uniqueKeys.contains(searchedKey))
            return v;
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```